# Why do we need special treatment of multiline string literals in programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, string-literals

Python has """ for multiline string literals.
C/C++ use \ at the end of a line to split a string literal across multiple lines.
Go uses `` for the same.

Can a language not support multiline string literals only with a single quote character?
Why not have multiline string literals as the default and only supported form?

Answer (score 0):

Python also support \ at the end of a line to split a string literal across multiple lines.